# Codekit throwing up error with zurb-foundation 3 installed

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

Having trouble with Codekit/Compass. Know lots of people have had issues with this but none of the solutions I've seen have worked and my problem seems a little different. I've installed the zurb-foundation gem and created a new project with it. This project is being watched by CodeKit. If I compile the project in the terminal it seems to do it fine, if I use CodeKit, I get this error:

***"LoadError on line 2 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/zurb-foundation-3.1.1/lib/zurb-     foundation.rb: no such file to load -- foundation/version"***

Irritatingly, the file /foundation/version.rb does exist where it should! Is CodeKit looking in the wrong place somehow? (despite navigating to the zurb-foundation.rb file perfectly?).

Anyone had this issue before? Please note this is not the same issue as CodeKit not being able to find the gem, as it is finding it but throwing up another error.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like I fixed it by pointing the Compass compiler to the one found in "usr/bin" rather than CodeKit's external compiler. Saw lots of people talking about doing the same thing with the SASS compiler. Still not sure why I had to do this!

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a short video explaining where to change CodeKit prefs for Foundation](http://vimeo.com/51325827).

Sass and Compass defaults as well as an output path get changed.

Comment: I did this, but I'm still getting the error: 

LoadError on line 31 of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb: no such file to load -- zurb-foundation